# How to trigger a dependent workflow from the same branch as the caller

Tags: git, github, github-actions

Suppose I have a workflow file like this:

```yaml
name: deploy-image
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [ "build-image" ]
    types:
      - completed
```

So, when `build-image` is completed, `deploy-image` is triggered.

How can I make sure that if I trigger `build-image` manually (using `workflow_dispatch`) on a particular branch, then `deploy-image` will also be triggered from that branch?

Currently, `deploy-image` ends up being triggered by the default (`master`) branch.

[image]

I have tried adding some parameters to `actions\checkout` but it's not working as expected.

```yaml
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
```

Comment: turns out I was testing it wrong. the `ref` thing works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Even though it doesn't look like it, but the `ref` in `actions/checkout` does work. I confirmed by adding `git branch`.

```yaml
name: deploy-image
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [ "build-image" ]
    types:
      - completed

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read
  packages: read
  issues: write

jobs:
  deploy-image-cu-en:
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}

      - run: git branch
```

[image]